# Eclipse Luna: how restore main menu?

Tags: eclipse

From settings in `Window` I hid some elements and `Window` too - how I can restore default view? Maybe I can edit something in configuration files?

[image: eclipse luna dark]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override file `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi` with this (Stackoverflow not allow me to post file here)

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s8/sh/2f5148cc-82be-4bfd-b30b-6abad5233c12/0c1cec43832ea07f13fe1912bb1f490d

This is settings of GUI from default Eclipse `Luna`.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the name of the perspective and choose "Reset", this will set the default settings of the perspective.